# Git and git merge --no-ff timer_redis

Tags: git, github

I tired to clean my master repo and did a

```
git rm -rf * 
git commit -m 't'
git push origin master
```

I then tried to do the following from the master branch.

```
git merge --no-ff timer_redis
```

Per the below error messages, where do I start?  Why is this happening?  I simply want to move a repo timer_redis to master.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/workspace/Amazon-Products-Crawler-1$ git merge --no-ff timer_redis
CONFLICT (delete/modify): LaunchCrawler.py deleted in HEAD and modified in timer_redis. Version timer_redis of LaunchCrawler.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (delete/modify): config_files/config.txt deleted in HEAD and modified in timer_redis. Version timer_redis of config_files/config.txt left in tree.
CONFLICT (delete/modify): config_files/default.json deleted in HEAD and modified in timer_redis. Version timer_redis of config_files/default.json left in tree.
CONFLICT (delete/modify): config_files/proxy_list.txt deleted in HEAD and modified in timer_redis. Version timer_redis of config_files/proxy_list.txt left in tree.
CONFLICT (delete/modify): config_files/ubuntu_install.sh deleted in HEAD and modified in timer_redis. Version timer_redis of config_files/ubuntu_install.sh left in tree.
CONFLICT (delete/modify): debugasin.txt.log deleted in HEAD and modified in timer_redis. Version timer_redis of debugasin.txt.log left in tree.
CONFLICT (delete/modify): ec2_shutdown_monitor.py deleted in HEAD and modified in timer_redis. Version timer_redis of ec2_shutdown_monitor.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (delete/modify): getPageParser.py deleted in HEAD and modified in timer_redis. Version timer_redis of getPageParser.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (delete/modify): includes/utility.py deleted in HEAD and modified in timer_redis. Version timer_redis of includes/utility.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (delete/modify): temp_tables/error404_core_1.txt deleted in HEAD and modified in timer_redis. Version timer_redis of temp_tables/error404_core_1.txt left in tree.
CONFLICT (delete/modify): temp_tables/error_core_1.txt deleted in HEAD and modified in timer_redis. Version timer_redis of temp_tables/error_core_1.txt left in tree.
CONFLICT (delete/modify): temp_tables/redo_core_1.txt deleted in HEAD and modified in timer_redis. Version timer_redis of temp_tables/redo_core_1.txt left in tree.
CONFLICT (delete/modify): threaded_crawl.py deleted in HEAD and modified in timer_redis. Version timer_redis of threaded_crawl.py left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing 'repository' and 'branch'. What you've done with `git rm -rf *` and `git commit -m 't'` is wipeout every file in your `master` branch. Then you pushed that (version controlled change) to your `origin` repository.

The `timer_redis` branch contains all those files you deleted, so when you merge it in, it throws a merge conflict on any file that exists in `timer_redis` that was also modified in `timer_redis`.

There are no workflows I can think of where you'd issue `git rm -rf *` and then continue using that branch history. If you want to make `master` look like `timer_redis` (and don't want any changes that exist in `master` but not `timer_redis`) try this:

```
git checkout timer_redis
git branch -D master
git checkout -B master timer_redis
git push -f origin master
```

That will delete your local's `master` branch, branch a new local `master` off `timer_redis`, then forcibly overwrite `origin`'s version of `master` with the new branch.

Comment: Instead of deleting (`git branch -D`) and recreating the `master` branch, one could alternativelly `git reset --hard timer_redis` while being on `master`.

Comment: git reset --hard timer_redis - this worked too.  Thanks all for clearing that up